# Checkout failure on last step

Tags: php, magento, pdo, checkout

I was just on the verge of turning my site live, as I had to update my database to the sites current standards for sales orders and transactions and what not so they fell just in line. I imported the sales files from the live database to the soon to be live database, which had been working perfectly prior to this. Once the updated sales and orders files were updated, my checkout process fails on the very last step of hitting 'Place Order' .. It goes into the submitting process, then simply comes up with a popup message stating "There was an error processing your order. Please contact us or try again later." Click okay, and you just stare at your waiting cart. I have looked around and tried a few things, to no avail. So I come to you all knowing stack crew!

This is the error log I am getting now;

```
    exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number:     parameter was not defined' in /www/www/store/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
    Stack trace:
    #0 /www/www/store/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement-    >execute(Array)
    #1 /www/www/store/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
    #2 /www/www/store/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
    #3 /www/www/store/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
    #4 /www/www/store/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `sales_f...', Array)
    #5 /www/www/store/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `sales_f...', Array)
    #6 /www/www/store/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(825): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
    #7 /www/www/store/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Quote.php(169): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchOne(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
    #8 /www/www/store/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php(1637): Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote->isOrderIncrementIdUsed('100014532')
    #9 /www/www/store/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(147): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->reserveOrderId()
    #10 /www/www/store/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(249): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitOrder()
    #11 /www/www/store/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php(785): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitAll()
    #12 /www/www/store/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(579): Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->saveOrder()
    #13 /www/www/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->saveOrderAction()
    #14 /www/www/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveOrder')
    #15 /www/www/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
    #16 /www/www/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
    #17 /www/www/store/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    #18 /www/www/store/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
    #19 {main}

    Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid         parameter number: parameter was not defined' in /www/www/store/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
    Stack trace:
    #0 /www/www/store/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
    #1 /www/www/store/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
    #2 /www/www/store/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
    #3 /www/www/store/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `sales_f...', Array)
    #4 /www/www/store/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `sales_f...', Array)
    #5 /www/www/store/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(825): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
    #6 /www/www/store/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Quote.php(169): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchOne(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
    #7 /www/www/store/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php(1637): Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote->isOrderIncrementIdUsed('100014532')
    #8 /www/www/store/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(147): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->reserveOrderId()
    #9 /www/www/store/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(249): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitOrder()
    #10 /www/www/store/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php(785): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitAll()
    #11 /www/www/store/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(579): Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->saveOrder()
    #12 /www/www/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->saveOrderAction()
    #13 /www/www/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveOrder')
    #14 /www/www/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
    #15 /www/www/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
    #16 /www/www/store/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    #17 /www/www/store/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
    #18 {main}
```

I can see they are both dealing with the same invalid parameter, but I assume if I just fix that one single parameter (which is probably just the parameter for my one personally made user account I assume) it would still error for some other, not effectively solving the issue. So I have to ask, does this give anyone an idea of what the heck I did to blow up my store?! Thanks for your time guys, truly!

Comment: Something is trying to set a parameter in a prepared query using a PDO. But the parameter was not defined when the query was prepared. But without any further information this will be a guessing game.

You said you "looked around and tried a few things". What did you find, what did you try and what was the result?

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/246805/ this is a similar thread i looked thru, and tried possible fixes such as moving the quote file and altering it, but that still continued same issue and even built another, so that was throw away.. ive tried redoing the db import multiple times making sure foreign keys were disabled since magento plays on those hooks all the time, and still no change.

Comment: That thread discusses a completely different issue. You need to search for the error you are getting: "Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined". Also check if you are running the latest version of this Magento software. Otherwise this may very well be a bug, you might want to join in on their own forum and report it. Because something is very wrong in there; their code has prepared a SQL query and then tries to set a non-existing parameter in it. Sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: Oops, completely linked the wrong page! http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/264446/P0/ that was the page in reference to this issue. They do talk about it being a possible bug as well though.

Comment: That thread also discusses a different error. Don't look at the big stack trace. They always look the same. (Well, kind of.) Only the first line is important to you, especially the error code: HY093. That indicates the core problem. I would really open a topic in their forum and include the same complete error messages and stack traces as you posted here.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out I was looking for the wrong thing. I would definitely goto the magento forums, but they seem to have a massive bot spam going on that basically makes using their forums useless. I suppose I will look around some more for the HY093.. It is just so frustrating that I was basically finished and ready to wrap it up! and BAM! haha. Thanks again Gerben

Comment: @Gerben Always look at the big stack trace — knowing where the query was kicked off by code more likely to have been edited is key to tracking this sort of thing down.

Comment: @AlanStorm Jeff didn't strike me as the kind of guy that hacks the Zend database engine.

Answer (score 0):

First, looking at your specific error

> exception 'PDOException' with message  SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid         parameter number: parameter was not defined

This is PHP's database layers saying "someone used me wrong".  Specifically, it looks like someone used a parameterized query where they included a blank and/or invalid parameter.

Second, looking at your stack trace, I noticed this.

```
/www/www/store/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Quote.php(169): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchOne(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
```

Specifically, it looks like you, or someone, has created a code pool override for the quote resource model.  Everything else being equal, I'd say it's likely the change you made to this file from the file in core is what's causing your problem.  Likely in this method (around line 169)

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Quote.php
public function isOrderIncrementIdUsed($orderIncrementId)
{
    $adapter   = $this->_getReadAdapter();
    $bind      = array(':increment_id' => (int)$orderIncrementId);
    $select    = $adapter->select();
    $select->from($this->getTable('sales/order'), 'entity_id')
        ->where('increment_id = :increment_id');
    $entity_id = $adapter->fetchOne($select, $bind);
    if ($entity_id > 0) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

My guess is you've either jiggered with the `$bind` array

```
$entity_id = $adapter->fetchOne($select, $bind);
```

or included additional query parameters in the SQL that aren't accounted for.

```
->where('increment_id = :increment_id');
```

Comment: Up until I was troubleshooting this error, I never touched that quote.php (to my knowledge atleast, maybe some extension tapped it possibly?) But that said, when I did the import, I just imported all the sales_* files to update the backend orders and shipping (which was successful) but obviously thru the wrench into the checkout, do you think importing the catalog with the sales_* and possibly even customers too all together would have any changed effect?

Comment: 1. Someone edited it or it wouldn't be in local.  2. Selectively importing magento database tables is insanity and leads only to tear. 3. Why guess at the error hen PHP is telling you the problem — all you need to do is figure out why $bind/the parameters are bad and you'll have your answer.

Comment: Well thank you for the insight :) I'm definitely going to be looking more into this indepth tomorrow, I am still pretty fresh to all of this.. I will look into the staged version and see if there are any changes in those files, namely the quote.php compared to my local version

Comment: Especially point 2... Magento's database interactions are more complex than most relational systems bother with and it's easy to do it wrong.

Comment: Just a follow up; I was able to get my cart working again. I believe the main issue was having the ability to shop multiple times, as the first one would give a certain id, and be fine, the second attempted purchase would try to use the same id and clash. As you already know, I am new and kind of learning trial by fire. I removed the entire local quote.php area, since I only included that *afterwards* while troubleshooting. It then just gave me the error; 

'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '100014536' for key 'UNQ_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_INCREMENT_ID''

Comment: Which after a little digging, gave the idea that the eav entity was being played with, which I did not carry over when I kind of merged the two databases (I know, insanity..) I wasn't particularly looking for this to work, but maybe lead me into the right direction of it starting to work properly. I brought along the customers, the store eav's, and again all of the sales_* files.

Low and behold, it seems to be working. No exceptions and no system warnings. Multiple sales went through. I should probably look forward to some issues in the future.. is it crazy to think this may be behind me?